# Google Sheets: Check a number of cells for a specific range of dates

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to check if a number of cells, containing multiple rows and cols, contains dates from another range (in this case days off). If the dates match I'd like to color the cell red using a conditional comment.

```
      | Col A      | Col B      | Col ?
    ----------------------------------------
    1 | Dates 1    | Dates 2    | Days off 
    ----------------------------------------    
    2 | ma 20 feb. | ma 6 mrt.  | wo 22 feb.
    3 | wo 22 feb. | wo 8 mrt.  | do 2 mrt.
    4 | do 23 feb. | do 9 mrt.  | do 9 mrt.
    5 | di 28 feb. | di 14 mrt. | do 16 mrt.
    6 | do 2 mrt.  | do 16 mrt. | 
    7 | vr 3 mrt.  | vr 17 mrt. |
```

So in the example above cell A3 matches an off day and should be coloured red. Same goes for cell A6, cell B4 and cell B6.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `Column ?` is ColumnF, please select A:B and in Conditional formatting apply a Custom formula is of:

```
=match(A1,$F:$F,0)
```

and select red.

[MATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378)

The above is case insensitive but you may need to be careful with spaces.